# How to translate an odoo email template but no invoice document attached

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, qweb, odoo-view

I have translated Odoo email templates from English to Spanish, Italian and French but I need to send the attached invoice in Spanish always, no matter the language.

How can I do that?

I have tried:

- specifying `<field name="lang">es_ES</field>` but it translates the email template too.
- forcing `<t t-raw="translate_doc(doc_id, doc_model, 'es_ES', 'wms_report.report_document')"/>` but it throws an error because param has to be an attribute of object.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can write this code and change your report template into partner's language.For ex. If your Invoice report partner's language is Spanish then report will print in Spanish lang.

  <template id="report_custom_invoice">
     <t t-call="report.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
            <t t-call="custom_template.report_invoice_custom" t-
               lang="o.partner_id.lang"/>
            </t>
        </t>
  </template>
```

Comment: thank you but, I don't want to translate the document. I want send the email translated to italian, french, whatever... but the attachment always in spanish.

Comment: Okay. So for that you have to create your attachment template in Spanish. And for email template you have to change translation of your mail in below path  (This is for odoo-v10).                                                                                         settings > technical > Email > Templates. And change your mail into Italian,french,whatever you want.

Comment: Well. I'm working with Odoo 8. Maybe, soon, I'll migrate to Odoo 10. Thanks